# Symfony skip JWT authentication for API if logged in

Tags: php, symfony

i have a security related question for my symfony 5 project.

I have secured the main page with hwiOAuthBundle and API secured with lexik jwt.

My goal is, that a user who is authenticated in the browser can access the api without a jwt,
how i can archive this?

Here my security.yaml:

```
firewalls:
  dev:
    pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
    security: false
  api_login:
    pattern: ^/api/login$
    stateless: true
    anonymous: true
    provider: in_memory
    json_login:
      check_path: /api/login
      success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
      failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
      require_previous_session: false
  api:
    pattern: ^/api
    stateless: true
    provider: in_memory
    guard:
      authenticators:
        - 'App\Security\MyAuthenticator'
    entry_point: 'App\Security\MyAuthenticator'
  main:
    anonymous: ~
    provider: hwi
    logout:
      path: app_logout
    oauth:
      resource_owners:
        google: "/login/check-google"
      login_path: /login
      use_forward: false
      failure_path: /login
      default_target_path: /
      oauth_user_provider:
        service: 'App\Security\GoogleOAuthUserProvider'
access_control:
  - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
  - { path: ^/api/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
  - { path: ^/api, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
  - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.